# Configure Tensorflow on GPU Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

How to set following config "gpu_options.allow_growth = True" for Tensorflow, using Java API?

I tried in this way:

```
model.session().runner()
                .setOptions("gpu_options.allow_growth = True".getBytes())
                .feed("image_tensor", input).fetch("detection_scores")
                .fetch("detection_classes").fetch("detection_boxes").fetch("num_detections").run();
```

I get the following error: Unparseable RunOptions proto.

Comment: The JAVA API is not ready for this configuration. It is specified that is experimental. No solutions work for me. So I do not know how to proceed with the status for this post.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the way to configure:

```
      ConfigProto config = ConfigProto.newBuilder()
                .setGpuOptions(GPUOptions.newBuilder().setAllowGrowth(true))
                .build();

      model.session().runner()
                    .setOptions(config.toByteArray())
                    .feed("image_tensor", input).fetch("detection_scores")
                    .fetch("detection_classes").fetch("detection_boxes").fetch("num_detections").run();
```

Comment: Looks good (too). Probably even a bit "more good" than my answer ;-)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this should not work. The `setOptions()` is taking a [RunOptions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session.Runner.html#setOptions(byte%5B%5D)) protocol buffer, instead of a `ConfigProto`.

Answer (score 1):

The API [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session.Runner#setOptions(byte%5B%5D)) says:

> public Session.Runner setOptions (byte[] options)
>
> (Experimental method): set options (typically for debugging) for this run.
>
> The options are presented as a serialized RunOptions protocol buffer.

Still looking for an exact example, but I assume: just taking a string and turning that into an array of bytes isn't what you should be doing.

These [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.tensorflow.Session) indicate that you need something like:

```
Session.Run r = runner.setOptions(RunStats.runOptions()).runAndFetchMetadata();
fetchTensors = r.outputs;

if (runStats == null) {
  runStats = new RunStats();
}
```

Long story short: you have to dig into [RunStats](https://github.com/baidu-research/tensorflow-allreduce/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/RunStats.java) to figure how to get your options in there, to then provide an object of that class to the `setOptions()` method.

Comment: [RunOptions protocol buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto)

Comment: @Adelin That is a config file. That won't help you getting it "into" the setOptions() call. See the updates I made in the meantime.